# I need some tutorials about CFNetwork in iphone

Tags: iphone, cfnetwork

I am developing a stock software,the client will receive the data from the server,so I want to use the CFNetwork.
and where can I find the tutorial "getting Started with networking",thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try these link i hope u get what u want.

http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/

http://oreilly.com/iphone/excerpts/iphone-sdk/network-programming.html

http://www.raddonline.com/blogs/geek-journal/iphone-sdk-testing-network-reachability/

Answer (score 0):

Go to xcode => Organizer => Documentation => iOS 4.x Library => Frameworks => CFNetwork there are 2 Programming Guides.